# What is the server.ca file?

Tags: ssl

I have a VPS with Directadmin panel. I have two files in my ssl.crt in the path `/etc/httpd/conf` which include `server.ca` and `server.crt`. My question is how is the first one originally created. My guess is that it is created after enabling ssl for Directadmin login.

Any ideas about to the essence of this file?

Comment: What makes you ask? Do you, for example, want to regenerate it?

Comment: @ Michael Kjörling That's right. I inadvertently removed the file and was thinking of how I can regenerate it.

Comment: You say you "have" the two, now you say you "removed" one. While it appears you have received an answer that might help, it's often easier to provide a good answer to a question that states the end goal. (For example: "I accidentally deleted /etc/httpd/conf/server.ca, which I believe has something to do with Directadmin. I don't have backups. What can I do to regenerate this file?")

Comment: Sorry. I meant a hypothetical situation, or rather what I originally "had". But you're right I should have stated the problem originally by mentioning that I have removed server.ca.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example to make it clear for you, because I think it is a little bit hard to understand the basics of ssl from your VPS panel:

**Security:**
Let's suppose I own reallycoolthings.com and people are buying cool things from me. Now I want to ensure my transactions are secure because if one of me users gets "hacked" (i.e stolen credit card) it will be some nasty reputation for my online store. Another reason I want https:// in front of my website is because it might appear red on someone's screen because the anti-virus doesn't trust it and I lose the client. So security is a good thing - how does it work.

**Self-signed** (like your case) certificates.
I set up, let's say openssl, I named my self as a certificate authority, so I can sign certificates with my name (reallycoolthings.com). Then I generate a server certificate which says this server is reallycoolthings.com and i sign it myself! (Isn't that cool?) Now for each client who connects to my site I issue a key and say look mister client while you hold this key and authenticate to the server our communication is secure and it is very unlikely that you will get "hacked". Which (like your case) works, on a technical level.

But who trusts a certificate signed by the issuer one could wonder? If I really owned that shop and you visited my site, your web browser would issue a warning and say THIS CONNECTION IS UNTRUSTED : they claim to be secure but I don't know who signed this security certificate. This is where you click I understand the risk, add exception (for those who dare AND understand the risks) or get the hell out of there.

This is where **real** certificate authorities come in, say https://www.verisign.com
I contact verisign and say look gentlemen I own this online store I am not really skimming people's accounts once I get their credit cards, I own a legit business etc. And these guys issue a **real** certificate for you! Your browser now sees that your site has been signed by verisign so the address bar at your client site is green, so he can use his credit card and sleep well at night.

So server.ca is your own certificate authority and server.crt is your certificate that you are who you say who you are signed by your self. Self-signed cetrtificates work on the technical level (i.e your secure login at the VPS panel) but are useless for commercial applications.

Answer (score 3):

When you enabled SSL login, the system created a self-signed certificate file server.crt. The server.ca is the certificate authority.

Comment: And who is the certificate authority then? (Excuse me if it is a silly question)

Comment: Do you mean entities such as DigiCert, SSL.com, etc. In that case I should say I have not bought any such certificates. Still Apache won't work without it.